# Are there any ways to get error message displayed by mocha.js html reporter to be saved into variable and alerted into other php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mocha.js

Does anyone know how to get the error message produced by mocha.js html reporter to be saved into some variable and alert into a php file. For example like codeacademy did, when user submit their code codeacademy will run the test and the error will be displayed into user. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this [Growl Jquery popup](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. But i mean the error message is being produced by a test runner called mocha.js like this http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/images/reporter-html.png. What i wanted is to when the test result produce error i want to get the string and alert it into othe php file. but i don't know how to get the error string cause the reporter will display it automatically.